# What is the white felt-like material between the heat shield tiles and stainless steel skin of Starship likely to be?

Tags: spacex-starship, thermal

I suspect that the white padding material between the tile and the stainless steel skin might be [Nomex Felt][1], but I don't really know. Nomex was used on the Space Shuttle.

> Flame-Resistant Felt - Nomex® (also called meta-aramid felt) is a high-temperature felt that protects against extreme heat.

[image: Flame-Resistant Felt]

Is there a newer, better material that Starship might be using or of is meta-aramid felt still the most likely candidate material for this application?

Comment: Nomex was used on the Shuttle where temperatures didn't exceed 371C:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_thermal_protection_system#Materials    If the temperatures are expected to be higher I guess it would be some other sort of ceramic fibre blanket: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineral_wool#High-temperature_mineral_wool